# Authorise user to edit only their account with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to allow user to edit their account, and only their account, without using Devise and / or Cancan.

I have the following in `application_controller` :

```
helper_method :current_user
helper_method :require_proprio

private

def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end

def require_proprio
    unless current_user == (params[:id])
        render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/422", :status => 500
     end
end
```

Here's the `users_controller` :

```
before_filter :require_proprio , :only => [ :edit, :update]
```

But when I'm connected with the `user.id = 10`, for example, I can't access to the page `http://localhost:3000/users/10/edit`. The page `public/422` appears. I tried also to access `http://localhost:3000/users/11/edit`, and the result is the same (public/422).

Does someone have an idea of the way I can resolve it ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unless current_user == (params[:id])
```

current_user is an object, so this will never be true. Try:

```
unless current_user.id == params.fetch(:id).to_i
```

Comment: It works. Thank you so much. I have to wait ten minutes to accept your answer. So I'll be back in 11 minutes.